# Close active div when other show / hide div buttons clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking at show / hide div dropdown links. I've found a pen of what i'm trying to do. I would like the active div to close automatically when another link is clicked and opened. At the moment the user must close the active div before viewing another. I'm new to JS so any help is appreciated.

[Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pqorog)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* hide all content divs */
  $('.toggle-content').hide();

  $('.toggle-trigger').click(function() {
    /* if the clicked item is active*/
    if ($('.toggle-trigger').hasClass('active')) {
      /* hide the next content div*/
      $(this).next('.toggle-content').slideUp();
      /* and remove the active class*/
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }

    /* if the cliked item is NOT active */
    else {
      /* slide the content div dwon */
      $(this).next('.toggle-content').slideDown();
      /* and add the active class*/
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $("a.dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $div = $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown);
      $div.toggle();
      $("div.dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
      return false;
    });
  });

  $('html').click(function() {
    $("div.dropdown-container").hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a tap is clicked you could iterate over all other taps and close them if active:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* hide all content divs */
  $('.toggle-content').hide();

  $('.toggle-trigger').click(function() {

    /* close all other taps but not current clicked tap */
    closeActiveTap(this);

    /* if the clicked item is active*/  
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
      /* hide the next content div*/
      $(this).next('.toggle-content').slideUp();
      /* and remove the active class*/
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    } 

    /* if the cliked item is NOT active */
    else {
      /* slide the content div dwon */

      $(this).next('.toggle-content').slideDown();
      /* and add the active class*/ 
      $(this).toggleClass('active');

    }
  });

});

function closeActiveTap(current){

  $('.toggle-trigger').each(function(index,tap){
    if(current!==tap && $(tap).hasClass('active')){
      $(tap).removeClass('active');
      $(tap).next('.toggle-content').slideUp();
    }
  });

}
```

function *closeActiveTap* takes an param *current* (current clicked tap) to make sure that on all other taps DOM-operations should be applied onto but not on the current tap because the current tap is handled anyway when reaching if-else codeblock.

Hope this helps

Comment: Cool. The code works and your explanation makes perfect sense. Thanks for helping.